# How to change SFTP password without allowing SSH login?

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, password-management

I am running Debian server as an SFTP data storage for multiple users. I didn't allow users to login via ssh. Is there any way to users to change their password? Mostly they are using WinSCP client.

I have tried to expire their passwords but WinSCP didn't prompt them to change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: How exactly did you deny the ability to change their passwords?  Given the fact that SFTP is file transfer over SSH, there is a good chance, your users can actually connect to the server using an SSH client. I would need more information to submit a proper answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Well… SFTP is file transfer protocol and does not support any user management (password change) so in short, it is not possible in SFTP.

Only possibility is to allow SSH access only in order to change the password (eg. use `ForceCommand` with proxy selecting between `sftp-server` and `passwd` command), such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Script: /usr/local/bin/wrapper.sh 

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
    "/path/to/sftp-server")
        /path/to/sftp-server
        ;;
    "passwd")
        passwd
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Sorry. Only passwd to change password or sftp is allowed"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: I think the second echo statement in your default case is not relevant for this script.